# Travis CLI produces error in ruby project

Tags: ruby, travis-ci

I just want to use travis CLI to encrypt my environment variable and use it in `.travis.yml` file. However when I run a simple `travis login` command in my project directory it gives me this error:

```
/home/saurabh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2158:in `method_missing': undefined method `this' for #<Gem::Specification:0x55cf1c travis-1.8.2> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/saurabh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1057:in `find_active_stub_by_path'
    from /home/saurabh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:64:in `require'
    from /home/saurabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/travis-1.8.2/bin/travis:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/saurabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/travis:23:in `load'
    from /home/saurabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/travis:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/saurabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/saurabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

What can be the reason for this and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug in Rubygems:
https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1420

To fix it either try to update Rubygems to a newer version (I'm not sure if it's fixed there yet though), or manually edit `lib/rubygems/specification.rb` and add code like so:

```
@@ -3005,6 +3005,8 @@ def raw_require_paths # :nodoc:
      @require_paths
    end

 +  def this; self; end
 +
    extend Gem::Deprecate

    # TODO:
```

Patch source:
https://github.com/orenf/rubygems/commit/4a4b4758bd454b4f7525635aca5e8a00e47cab42

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the issue:

```
gem update --system
```

Comment: @FelixSFD Right, I was in a rush after debugging. Thanks.